# Design pattern for share calculating order totals

Tags: php, design-patterns, architecture

I want to solve two problems:

1. Share data between existing methods
2. Less coupling this methods

What pattern I can use for calculating totals?

```php
/** @var array $orderData */

// Ordered products total price
$orderedProductsTotal = $this->orderedProductsTotalPrice($orderData);

$total = $orderedProductsTotal;

// Shipping cost dependent on ordered products total price
$shippingCost = $this->shippingCost($orderedProductsTotal);
$total += $shippingCost;

// Client allowed credit, depends on ordered products total price
$total -= $this->credit($orderedProductsTotal);

// Available coupon depends on order data (i.e. special products in order, etc)
$total -= $this->coupon($orderData);

// Client personal discount applying on total amount, excluding shipping cost
$total -= $this->personalDiscount($total - $shippingCost);
```

I thinking about something like this

```php
$calcs = [
    'OrderProductsCalc',
    'ShippingCalc',
    'CreaditCalc',
    'CouponCalc',
    'PersonalDiscountCalc',
];

$total = 0;


foreach ($calcs as $v) {
    // How to share data between calculators?
    // Separated calculated total values of each calculator
    // Order data
    // Something else
    /** @var CalculatorInterface $calculator */
    $calculator = $this->container->get($v);
    $total = $calculator->getTotal($total);
}
```

This is a simple class dependents on Cart items

```php
class OrderProductsCalc implements CalcInterface
{
    private Cart $cart;

    public function __construct(Cart $cart)
    {
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }

    public function getTotal(float $total): float
    {
        $subTotal = $this->cart->getTotal();

        return $total + $subTotal;
    }
}
```

`ShippingCalc` is simple too as it run next to `OrderProductsCalc`.

But `CreaditCalc::getTotal()` should receive as `$total` the `$subTotal` inner value from `OrderProductsCalc::getTotal()`.

```php
class CreaditCalc implements CalcInterface
{
    private $customer;

    public function __construct(Customer $customer)
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;
    }

    /**
     * @var float $total The $subTotal inner value from OrderProductsCalc::getTotal()
     */
    public function getTotal(float $total): float
    {
        $balance = $this->customer->getBalance();
        if ($balance) {
            $credit = min($balance, $total);
            
            if ($credit > 0) {
                $total -= $credit;
            }
        }
        
        return $total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`You can slightly modify design by utilizing command pattern.
You can create commands for
'OrderProductsCalc',
'ShippingCalc',
'CreaditCalc',
'CouponCalc',
'PersonalDiscountCalc'

Now you can do the total calculation by "chaining the commands"  to make a generic design.
Depending upon the calculation create the chain with the corresponding commands.
Pass the output of one command to next command.
Write the logic of command chaining in abstract Service class.
Create subclass depending upon different calculations
Psuedo code, something like(explains just the intent) in java.

```
abstract class Service{

constructor(commands){
    this.commands = commands
}

Command[] commands;

public final executeChain(){
    loop(command in commands){
        command.execute();
    }
    perform();
}
abstract protected void perform();
```

}

```
class CalculateTotal extends Service{
protected void perform(){
//specific
}
```

}